# Meaning of GLib-GIO-CRITICAL assertion error

Tags: ubuntu, runtime-error, glib

I successfully compiled the following program simple.cc:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = 
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::ApplicationWindow window;

  return app->run(window);
}
```

using the following command:

```
g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Which gave me the executable simple, but when I tried to run it, I got the following error:

```
(simple:2964): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_list_actions: assertion `application->priv->is_registered' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As far as I can tell, I have the latest and greatest GLib packages. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem as I have just started on the same tutorial. 
Replace:

```
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow window;
```

with

```
    GTK::Window window;
```

If you read the description of the code in the tutorial the latter is actually the code that is discussed.  Making this change made the program work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your window to the application instance. Create it like this:

```
Gtk::ApplicationWindow window(app);
```